# Why the Bootstrap Offset Class not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, offset

I am doing practice with Bootstrap 4. I have two columns in my web-page layout.i want to push the first column to right side by 3 columns in the Bootstrap 12 columns Grid system its not working. Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="CustomDiv">
                Column 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="CustomDiv">
                Column 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE:In CustomDiv class i just defined some styles like

```
.CustomDiv{
margin:3px;
min-height:300px;
background-color:black;
text-align:center;
font-size:large;
color:white;
```

}

[image]

Please help me out. I have already download new Bootstrap version and also create a new project but none helps. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the latest documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns. Offsets have changed.

`col-*-offset=-*` has changed to `offset-*-*`.